# thread safety of map when using UUID as key

Tags: java, spring, concurrency

There is a service that contains a `final` field.

```
@Service
public class RegularService {
    private final DataMap map = new DataMap();
    ....
}
```

This `final` field has class `DataMap` that looks something like this

```
class DataMap {
    private Map<UUID, String> content1 = new HashMap<>();
    private Map<UUID, String> content2 = new HashMap<>();

    void updateContent(UUID id, String data) {
        if (content1.containsKey(id)) {
           ....
           return;
        }


        if (content2.containsKey(id)) {
            content1.put(id, data);
            content2.remove(id);
            return;
        }
        content2.put(id, data);
    }
```

The question is - does `updateContent` features the race condition? The thing is that using `UUID` in theory means that the same entries will never be accessed by different threads...

If it is then is there a need to synchronize the whole `updateContent` method or just using `ConcurrentHashMap` will suffice?

Comment: Just because you're not modifying the same _entry_ at the same time doesn't make it thread safe.  The map data structure is still being modified by multiple threads and can break.

Comment: Precisely Louis ^^.

Comment: @LouisWasserman but would the break would look like? I always assumed that issue with thread safe maps is that we can corrupt the state when multiple threads access the same id - for example when writing & reading etc.

Comment: If you use the atomic update operations provided by the `ConcurrentMap` interface, especially the ones added in Java 8, then there's no issue.  Having two separate maps to update might be a problem -- and honestly the best solution might be to share one map and have values that include all the relevant data.

Comment: @lapots The issue with thread-unsafe maps is that multiple threads can corrupt it any way at al. It has nothing to do specifically with accessing the same key.

Comment: so in the end is a race condition in a plain sight?

Answer (score 1):

> The thing is that using UUID in theory means that the same entries will never be accessed by different threads...

This is simply just not true. This is not guaranteed. How did you come to this conclusion? I am interested to know.

> If it is then is there a need to synchronize the whole updateContent method or just using ConcurrentHashMap will suffice?

You don't necessarily have to synchronize the entire function, just the bit that modifies the map. You can use a ConcurrentHashMap to solve this, but there are major performance penalties to this.

Comment: Using `ConcurrentHashMap` is probably cheaper than synchronizing map access.

Comment: Yeah that is a fair statement, it would entirely depend on the type of access, whether it's read or write.

Comment: `This is simply just not true. This is not guaranteed. How did you come to this conclusion? I am interested to know.` What the application does is simply read the data from REST flow - upload part of data, upload another part of data and do it sequentially. But each REST flow works with UUID which are unique so in theory any update or read will deal with the separate UUID and with sequential REST access it will never corrupt the state.

Comment: @LouisWasserman cheaper than a lock for second `if` and the last `put`?

Comment: `ConcurrentHashMap` is very good at what it does, especially in more recent versions of Java.  I would expect it to beat locking in situations of moderate or higher contention.

Comment: @LouisWasserman should operations inside second `if` inside `updateContent` method done at the same time (aka with using locks) or separating them is ok? Personally I don't like the usage of two maps - one map with composite value would be better - but I haven't written this code.

Comment: It is not safe to sequence them.  Either use a lock or do them in the same map

Answer (score 1):

> thread safety of map when using UUID as key

Thread safety of maps really has nothing to do with the key object in question. Just because `UUID.randomUUID()` returns a unique UUID doesn't somehow guarantee thread safety.  The problem is around memory synchronization and how the threads will see and publish changes to the maps and coordinated the multiple map operations.

> The question is - does `updateContent()` feature a race condition?

Yes, it does.  First of all, you cannot update a `Map` using multiple threads without using a synchronized or concurrent `Map` implementation.  `ConcurrentHashMap` will take care of the modifications to the maps and publishing of the memory between threads to keep them in sync.  But because you are making multiple operations to the maps that need to be coordinated, you will need to add more synchronization.

> If it is then is there a need to synchronize the whole `updateContent()` method or just using ConcurrentHashMap will suffice?

Since you are making multiple changes to 2 maps, you will need to use `synchronized` or otherwise lock around the multiple operations.  Once you do that then there is no need to use `ConcurrentHashMap`.  You can either make the method `synchronized`, lock on one of the maps, or make a specific `final Object lockObject = new Object()` to use to lock around the operations.

For example, without a lock, there is nothing that protects thread1 to see that `content1` doesn't contain id XXX and then go forward to check `content2` right before thread2 adds it to `content1`.  So thread1 would overwrite thread2's `data` which is not what you'd want I assume.

Comment: ` The big question is if the map itself was created before the threads that are accessing it were created` - well, `RegularService` and consequentially the instance of  `DataMap` are instantiated before it is used by threads. But multiple threads can access the same map at the same time as method `updateContent` doesn't regulate the access to maps.

Comment: Sorry @lapots, I didn't fully grok your initial post.  I've edited my answer.